# Proving that $\exists x\in[0,1]:\sum\frac{b_n^2}{|x-a_n|}<\infty$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

> Let $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers s.t $\sum b_n<\infty$ and let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers in $[0,1]$. Prove that $\exists x\in[0,1]:\sum\frac{b_n^2}{|x-a_n|}<\infty$.
>
> Hint: Use Borel-Cantelli Lemma

I thought defining $X_n$ as indicators for existence of  $x\in[0,\frac 1 n]$ s.t $\sum\frac{b_n^2}{|x-a_n|}<\infty$ but I can't find any sufficient criterion for the convergence of the sum. I thought comparing this series to $\sum\frac{1}{|x-a_n|}<\infty$ but of course it diverges for every $x\in[0,1]$. How can I find the probability of this series to converge? Am I defining the events wrong?

Comment: You forgot a hypothesis on $(b_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\displaystyle f_n(x)=\frac{b_n}{\sqrt{|x-a_n|}}$. Then $f_n$ is in $L^1$ and
$$\int_0^1 f_n(t)dt=2b_n(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{1-a_n})\leq 4 b_n$$
Hence the series $\displaystyle \int_0^1f_n(t)dt$ is convergent. By the monotone convergence theorem, we get that $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} f_n(x)$ is in $L^1$. Hence $f(x)$ is finite a.e, and the series of general term $f_n(x)$ is convergent a.e. As if a positive series $c_n$ is convergent, then the series $c_n^2$ is also convergent, we are done.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't we have to use borel - cantelli here somewhere?

Comment: @Danis Fisher: Yes, but I do not know how to introduce Borel-Cantelli here, sorry...

Comment: didn't we have to prove that $f_n\le f_{n+1}$ in order to use the theorem?

Comment: We apply the monotone convergence theorem to $g_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$

Comment: oops. my mistake. thanks.